# Saving Matplotlib polar plot with TeX engine fails for some file formats, setup or bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib

With a polar plot and the use of MiKTeX as the LaTeX engine, matplotlib generates errors when saving the file to some formats.  This may be a bug in matplotlib or a problem with my setup.  I am posting here first, to see if this is a configuration issue or not, and then to see if others can recreate the failure on other systems (Mac, Linux, etc.) and other TeX engines. Note: saving the standard x-y plots using MiKTeX works as advertised.

My configuration:  Windows 10, and MiKTeX 2.9 with the latest updates.

Here is a minimum working example (not all file types are included).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)


plt.savefig('foo.png')  # Works
plt.savefig('foo.jpg')  # Works
plt.savefig('foo.tif')  # Works
# plt.savefig('foo.pdf')  # Fails
# plt.savefig('foo.svg')  # Fails
plt.show()
```

Comment: This very much looks like a matplotlib bug, which is windows-specific. Would you [create an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) for it? (To avoid confusion, put `plt.show()` after `savefig`, else even if it was working, it might save an empty figure.)

Comment: This bisects to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11381

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I will check out the githubI bisect you pointed out and create an issue if needed.  The `plt.show()` was moved as requested... good catch.

Comment: You don't need to check the PR this bisects to yourself; just create the issue and fill out the form as accurately as possible. (Of course you can also ask me to do it for you, but its nice to have the users create the issues for us to see that this is a real-world problem and to be able to ask for clarifications within the issue itself.)

Comment: Ok, did not understand what you meant by bisect.  The bug has been created: See [#14146](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14146)